# Get website source, getting extra symbols, winsock

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

Hello i have some problem with socket. I'm trying to get webpage source, i get everything what i need but between response header and page source i get some extra symbol, **so my question is** Why i getting those extra symbols.

I'm getting that "18ad" from somewhere...

Source got from page:

```
<..>
Server: Apache-Cloud
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 27 Sep 2012 14:46:43 GMT
Connection: close
X-Cache: M


18ad

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xh
<..>
```

hex view:

```
    char: X-Cache: M......18ad...<!DO
    hex : 58 2D 43 61 63 68 65 3A 20 4D 0D 0D 0A 0D 0D 0A 31 38 61 64 0D 0D 0A 3C 21 44 4F
```

Request header:

```
$GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: www.demotivation.us\r\n
Connection: close\r\n\r\n
```

My code:

```
char*       ip  = "www.demotivation.us";
char*       url = "92.61.41.215";

<..>
sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
sockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
sockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
<..>
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
connect(s, (SOCKADDR*)&sockAddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN);

<..>

// receive source to temporary buffer
do
{
    bytes = recv(s, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
    buffer[bytes] = '\0';

    cout << buffer;
} while(bytes > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `18ad` is part of the *chunked* encoding scheme. It means that the content is being downloaded in several *chunks* instead of one. The `18ad` indicates the size of the next chunk (6317 bytes in this case).

See [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) for a description.

Note that `recv()` can return `-1` on failure which should be checked for before being used as an array index.

Comment: Thank you for fast response, problem will be solved soon, and yes i'm using recv/send checks, just wanted to simplify it